# When and where was the first mention of Xanathar in any D&D publication?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

I've been told the beholder monster first appeared in Greyhawk (1975), but what was the first appearance of Xanathar in particular?
Title and year would be nice.

Comment: Related: [Origin of the Beholder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208558/75095).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 1987

The first appearance of [Xanathar](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Xanathar) is in the first edition supplement [Waterdeep and the North](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Waterdeep_and_the_North). A copy of which, that actually belongs to a friend, is somewhere in my garage.

For a bottle of single malt scotch (which I’m happy to share), I’ll tell you what adventuring in the Forgotten Realms was like back then.

Comment: Arguably their first appearance is *on* Waterdeep and the North - they appear to be the centrepiece of the cover art!

Comment: Would you accept Belgian beer instead of scotch?

Comment: If you are ever in my neck of the woods, I have an Auchentoshan 21 year old I'd be happy to share for your war stories.  My memories only go back to AD&D in the mid 90s.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterdeep_and_the_North) has the cover of FR1, Waterdeep and the North with Xanathar and it's associates.